# geom_density with alpha vector

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'd like to plot several distributions with `geom_density`, and have all but one of them faded out.  How can I do this, as the following doesn't change the `alpha` as expected.

```
require("ggplot2")

data = rbind(
  data.frame(generation=1, samples=rnorm(90)),
  data.frame(generation=2, samples=rnorm(100)),
  data.frame(generation=3, samples=rnorm(110)),
  data.frame(generation=4, samples=rnorm(120)),
  data.frame(generation=5, samples=rnorm(130)),
  data.frame(generation=6, samples=rnorm(140))
)

maxGen = max(data$generation)

ggplot(data) + 
  geom_density(
    aes(
      colour= factor(generation), 
      x=samples,
      alpha=ifelse(data$generation == maxGen, 0.3, 1.0)
    )
  )
```

In case it makes a difference, the real thing adds a facet wrap across another variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One other option that works with `geom_density` is to specify colors with an alpha parameter directly in the `scales_color_manual` but in that case, it will take some more work to "scale" your plot for more colors.

```
cols <- scales::hue_pal()(6)
cols.alpha <- c(cols[1:5], grDevices::adjustcolor(cols[6], alpha.f = 0.3))

ggplot(data) + 
  geom_density(
    aes(
      colour = factor(generation), 
      x = samples,
    ), size = 1.5
  ) +
  scale_colour_manual(values = cols.alpha)
```

Answer (score 5):

Switched to `geom_line` and it seems to work:

```
require("ggplot2")

data = rbind(
  data.frame(generation=1, samples=rnorm(100)),
  data.frame(generation=2, samples=rnorm(100)),
  data.frame(generation=3, samples=rnorm(100)),
  data.frame(generation=4, samples=rnorm(100)),
  data.frame(generation=5, samples=rnorm(100)),
  data.frame(generation=6, samples=rnorm(100))
)

maxGen = max(data$generation)

ggplot(data) + 
  geom_line(
    aes(
      colour= factor(generation), 
      x=samples,
      alpha=I(ifelse(data$generation == maxGen, 1, 0.3))
    ),
    stat="density",
    size=1.5
  )
```

I have no idea what the `I` in the `I(ifelse(...` is doing, but it seems to stop extra stuff from showing up in the legend.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

If you want the transparency parameter to take an effect, you need to specify the `fill` parameter instead of color, which only affects the line of the plot:

```
ggplot(data) + geom_density(aes(fill= factor(generation), x=samples, alpha=generation == maxGen)) + 
    scale_alpha_manual(labels = c("TRUE" = "Max", "FALSE" = "NoMax"), values = c(0.1, 0.8)) + 
    theme(legend.title = element_blank())
```

[image]

Comment: I actually wanted to change the line alpha, but this put me on the right track.  Switched to using geom_line with stat="density" and it worked.